# How to pattern match for a list of strings

Tags: r

I am trying to find and replace some text based on fuzzy matching as follows.

**Aim**

I want to do this for a list of find and replaces. I dont know how to extend the current function to allow this to happen.

**Input**

Input text

```
 df <- data.frame(textcol=c("In this substring would like to find the radiofrequency ablation of this HALO",
                             "I like to do endoscopic submuocsal resection and also radifrequency ablation",
                             "No match here","No mention of this radifreq7uency ablati0on thing"))
```

**The attempt**

```
 ##### Lower case the text ##########
  df$textcol<-tolower(df$textcol)

  #Need to define the pattern to match and what to replace it with 
  matchPattern <- "radiofrequency ablation"


    findAndReplace<-function(matchPattern,rawText,replace)
{

positions <- aregexec(matchPattern, rawText, max.distance = 0.1)
regmatches(rawText, positions)
res <- regmatches(df$textcol, positions)
res[lengths(res)==0] <- "XXXX"  # deal with 0 length matches somehow

#################### Term mapping ####################
df$out <- Vectorize(gsub)(unlist(res), replace, rawText)
df$out
  }


 matchPatternRFA <- c("radiofrequency ablation")
repRF<-findAndReplace(matchPatternRFA,rawText,"RFA")
repRF
```

**The problem**
The above works fine for the replacement of one term, but what if I want to also replace endoscopic 'submucosal resection' with 'EMR' and 'HALO' with 'catheter'?

Ideally I'd like to create a list of terms to match but then how do I also specify how to replace them?

Comment: Its very different as a) Im using fuzzy find and replace b) Im asking how to run it over a list of find and replaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `asub` to replace approximate matches with a replacement string and define a matching list `L` that for each name defines its replacement.  Then run `Reduce` to perform the replacements.

```
asub <- function(pattern, replacement, x, fixed = FALSE, ...) {
  m <- aregexec(pattern, x, fixed = fixed)
  r <- regmatches(x, m)
  lens <- lengths(r)
  if (all(lens == 0)) return(x) else
  replace(x, lens > 0, mapply(sub, r[lens > 0], replacement, x[lens > 0]))
}

L <- list("radiofrequency ablation" = "RFA", 
      "endoscopic submucosal resection" = "EMR",
      "HALO" = "cathetar")

Reduce(function(x, nm) asub(nm, L[[nm]], x), init = df$textcol, names(L))
```

giving:

```
[1] "In this substring would like to find the RFA of this cathetar"
[2] "I like to do EMR and also RFA"                                
[3] "No match here"                                                
[4] "No mention of this RFA thing"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup table with patterns and necessary replacements:

```
dt <-
  data.table(
    textcol = c(
      "In this substring would like to find the radiofrequency ablation of this HALO",
      "I like to do endoscopic submuocsal resection and also radifrequency ablation",
      "No match here",
      "No mention of this radifreq7uency ablati0on thing"
    )
  )

dt_gsub <- data.table(
  textcol = c("submucosal resection",
              "HALO",
              "radiofrequency ablation"),
  textcol2 = c("EMR", "catheter", "RFA")
)

for (i in 1:nrow(dt))
  for (j in 1:nrow(dt_gsub))
    dt[i]$textcol <-
  gsub(dt_gsub[j, textcol], dt_gsub[j, textcol2], dt[i, textcol])
```

Comment: Thanks.I have changed the code to be a function. How can I incorporate the function into your code so it can run over dt_gsub?